# Show rows and columns in a grid even without data

Tags: grid, ag-grid

How to show rows and columns in ag-grid even without data?I know when there is no data the grid collapses but how to make it visible few rows and columns?

Comment: if there are not data, then what to show in rows? You mean to say if there is no records then your grid gets collapsed? You can't see even columns?

Comment: Yes Paritosh i dont see the columns.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set height of the grid for that.

```
style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"
```

Check **[this Plunk for live example](https://plnkr.co/edit/Xq5sYEk0y3XpoJdd1h8A?p=preview)**

Try to add/remove line #9 in `app.component.ts` and see yourself.

Comment: @GrailsLearner you can mark it as answer to make other users understand that this is the solution to the issue